# I want to get a specific answer by comparing two columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this :

```
with base_data as 
( Select
receipt_date,
receipt_value,
receipt_customer_id
From table1 )
Select
count(distinct (receipt_customer_id) , sum(receipt_value)
From
base_data
where
(receipt_date:timestamp <= current_date - interval '1 month' and 
receipt_date: timestamp >= current_date - interval '2 month)
```

This basically gives me the number of distinct clients and their sum of receipt values for July and August considering the current month as September
I want to reduce this further and just want data for
distinct clients and sum of their receipt values
for whom there was no receipt in July i.e. they never transacted with us in July but came back in August basically they skipped a month and then transacted again.
I am unable to write this clause which I am putting in English below as a problem statement :
Give me the data for a distinct count of clients and their total sum of receipts who transacted with us in August but had no receipt value in July
I hope I am able to explain it. I have been racking my brain on this for a while but am unable to figure out a solution. Please help.

The current result looks like this
Count: 120
Sum: 207689
I want it reduced to (assumption)
Count: 12
Sum: 7000

Comment: Sample data would help.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I can see is with "sum of receipt values for July and August"; the return from your current query will depend upon when it is run (and will not be for calendar months). Lets put that aside and simplify/fix (the query as stated does not run) your query to one that will list all transactions in August (I think its simpler to understand using hard coded dates for now):

```
Select
receipt_customer_id, sum(receipt_value)
From
table1
where
-- Transacted in August
receipt_date >= '2020-08-01'::timestamp and
receipt_date < '2020-09-01'::timestamp 
group by receipt_customer_id;
```

We can now add another clause to the `where` to filter out customers with transactions totalling $0/NULL (so total of $0 or no transactions at all) in July:

```
Select
receipt_customer_id, sum(receipt_value)
From
table1 t
where
-- Transacted in August
t.receipt_date >= '2020-08-01'::timestamp and 
t.receipt_date < '2020-09-01'::timestamp  
and (
   select coalesce(sum(receipt_value), 0)
   from table1 
   where 
   receipt_customer_id = t.receipt_customer_id and
   -- Transacted in July
  receipt_date >= '2020-07-01'::timestamp and
   receipt_date < '2020-08-01'::timestamp      
 )  = 0
group by receipt_customer_id;
```

or if you just want the count of customers and sum of `receipt_value`:

```
Select
count(distinct receipt_customer_id), sum(receipt_value)
From
table1 t
where
-- Transacted in August
t.receipt_date >= '2020-08-01'::timestamp and 
t.receipt_date < '2020-09-01'::timestamp  
and (
   select coalesce(sum(receipt_value), 0)
   from table1 
   where 
   receipt_customer_id = t.receipt_customer_id and
   -- Transacted in July
  receipt_date >= '2020-07-01'::timestamp and
   receipt_date < '2020-08-01'::timestamp      
 )  = 0
```

See this [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6rWM3NvKcjfF1Af3hp78Vb/4) for a test of this (feel free to use this if you want to ask follow-up questions). Note that if you want to reintroduce `current_date` you can do so (but you probably want to calculate the start of the month [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) can help with this).